# How to remove a Language Selector Porlet from a page of Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I've added a `Language Selector` portlet to a public page of `Liferay 7` but now I've decided to remove it. Unfortunately, there is no remove option on its menu.

You can see the menu image below.

[image: LanguageSelector Portlet]

How can I remove it from this page?

Liferay version is: `liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga4`

Comment: Is this added manually or automatically through the theme or layout template? How to find out: Change the theme to classic, change the layout template to some built-in template and validate if it's still there. Validate if you can move it around on the page and if it retains that position. If you can't move it around, or if it disappears with a built-in theme: It's your theme that forces the portlet to appear on every page. Otherwise: Check that you have permission to add this portlet to a page.

Comment: @OlafKock. I have an Admin permission, I've changed the theme to classic one( default Liferay 7 theme) and again there is no remove option. notice that all other portlets have got remove option. One more thing, after adding it to a page (each page) I cant relocate it. I've added it from right side of page by a add button.

Comment: @ElyasHadizadeh It's embedded portlet issue with a page. You can remove embedded portlet in LR 6.X by going page (In Control panel). I also have the same problem and I perform below step to resolve. It's work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Login with 'Site Admin' role**

`Control Panel - >  Configuration -> Components page`

`Aprrox page 3 - > Language Selector -> click -> uncheck "Active" -> Save.`

It will remove portlet from Liferay

`Now, Go to your Page ( Where 'Language Selector') -> click on 3 dots -> you can see 'Remove' option.`

**Rollback**

`Control Panel - >  Configuration -> Components`

`Aprrox page 3 - > Language Selector -> click -> check "Active" -> Save.`